# ACCESS autonumber using DCount function

Tags: sql, ms-access

Newbie using Access and I am not sure what to do next ;(

I am trying to add autonumber using MS Access query. I have 2667 ASSET_TYPE records in ASSET_insert_02 query.

I am using DCount function as follows:

```
Number: DCount("*","ASSET_insert_02","[ASSET_TYPE]<=" & [ASSET_insert_02]![ASSET_TYPE])
```

But the function keeps showing #Error with the alert:

> "The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error:
>
> "the object doesn't contain the Automation Object "TYPE01."

Any chance of solving this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, avoid domain aggregates like `DCount` in queries, but use a subquery instead. This benefits performance, and avoids issues with string concatenation. The notable exception is that subqueries often cause queries to not be updateable, so when a query needs to be updateable, you can use `DCount` with proper quoting.

As a subquery, that statement would be:

```
Number: (SELECT COUNT(a.*) FROM ASSET_insert_02 a WHERE a.[ASSET_TYPE]<= [ASSET_insert_02].[ASSET_TYPE])
```

Answer (score 0):

If Asset_Type is *text*, you miss single-quotes:

```
Number: DCount("*","[ASSET_insert_02]","[ASSET_TYPE] <= '" & [ASSET_insert_02]![ASSET_TYPE] & "'")
```